# How to store user uploaded image from flask server in google storage bucket?

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I am trying to find a way to store an image uploaded in the flask server by a user in a google storage bucket.
This is my attempt to upload the image. It fails.

```
@app.route("/upload-image", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_image():
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            if request.files:
                image = request.files["image"]
                readImg = image.read()
                content = bytes(readImg)

                client = storage.Client().from_service_account_json(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'])
                print('1)')
                bucket = storage.Bucket(client, "uploaded-usrimg")
                print('2)')
                file_blob = bucket.blob(content)
                print('3)')
                
                return render_template('result.html', request=result.payload[0].display_name)
                # return render_template('homepage.html')
        
        except Exception as e:
            print('error creating image data')
            print(e)
```

My blob (image) does not upload to my bucket.
I get this error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jan/2021 18:40:58] "POST /upload-image HTTP/1.1" 500 -
1)
2)
error creating image data
'utf-8' codec can''t decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
[2021-01-13 18:41:11,663] ERROR in app: Exception on /upload-image [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2098, in make_response
    "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jan/2021 18:41:11] "POST /upload-image HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Any idea how to solve this error? Or another method in uploading to google bucket? Thanks so much.

Comment: check this https://gist.github.com/merqurio/c0b62eb1e1769317907f

Comment: Every time I try to import google.appengine I run into a module related error :( Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this error message is due to the way you are handling the image. In your code `readImg = image.read()`, you are decoding the image according to UTF-8 rules and encounter a byte sequence that is not allowed in UTF-8 encoding.

You need to open the image with `b` in the `open()` mode so that the file is read as binary and the contents remain as bytes.

```py
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

If you were using different file types, `byte XXXX in position 0` could also mean that the file is encoded incorrectly so, for example, you could try this or similar:

```py
open(path, encoding='utf-16') as f:
    contents = f.read()
```